# Implementation knockout custom binding with afterRender functionality

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm working with a list of images. The images are loaded dynamically; the list of references is stored in observableArray.
After a full load of the image list I want to connect handlers of DOM-elements. My implementation at the moment:

in View:

```
<div class="carousel_container" data-bind="template: { 'name': 'photoTemplate', 'foreach': ImageInfos, 'afterRender': renderCarousel }">
<script type="text/html" id="photoTemplate">
//...content of template
</script>
```

in ViewModel:

```
self.counterCarousel = 0;
self.renderCarousel = function (elements) {
    var allImagesCount = self.ImageInfos().length;
    self.counterCarousel++;

    if (self.counterCarousel >= allImagesCount) {
        self.counterCarousel = 0;
        // ... add handlers here
    }
}
```

This is a very ugly approach. In addition, user can add / delete images, so after each addition or removal is required remove all handlers and connect it again. How can I organize a custom binding to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this approach would not work -

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(ImageInfos(), function (image) {
    // ... add handlers here
});
```

Or better yet, bind an event to each item with a class of 'image-info' so that you don't have to redo the bindings when items are added or changed -

```
var afterRender = function (view) {
    bindEventToImages(view, '.image-info', doSomething);
};

var bindEventToImages= function (rootSelector, selector, callback, eventName) {
    var eName = eventName || 'click';
    $(rootSelector).on(eName, selector, function () {
        var selectedImage = ko.dataFor(this);
        callback(selectedImage);
        return false;
    });
};

function doSomething(sender) {
    alert(sender);
    // handlers go here
}
```

This binds an event to every class 'image-info' and on-click handles the calling element, executing doSomething.